# External entity links and API design

Tags: architecture

I'm designing a system and the core of the design is completely decoupled from our other systems and their bounded contexts.

The core entity to my new system is ENTITY_A.

When the tech teams integrate with the system, ENTITY_A will need to be associated with ENTITYB, or ENTITYC etc which are entities in other systems.  This will be done in an extensibility layer of the platform.

Two challenges I'd like some advice on:

- how do we model soft foreign keys (i.e storing id along with entity name)
- how do we enable search on our API allowing querying of
  ENTITY_A based on keys of ENTITY_B or ENTITY_C?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if there is a better approach than just store ENTITY_B.Id in ENTITY_A.BId. While this approach is fine, you should consider ability to query ENTITY_B data from system B and how strong system A relies on that data. In particular how system A should behave if B is not reachable or ENTITY_B is deleted.

I would recommend always begin with having some internal representation of external entities. This representation should hold data (other than key) that is important for system A but is unlikely to change in B or can be outdated. In my experience such kind of data always exists and dealing with outdated data in small isolated part of a system is usually easier than dealing with inconsistency in every part of a system. Internal representation also helps with updating data. It can hold last update time or synchronization status.

For example let ENTITY_A_B be an entity representing ENTITY_B in system A. We want UI in A able to display ENTITY_B.Name without querying B (for both performance and accessibility). So we can model entities in A like this:

```
ENTITY_A_B {
BId,
Name
}
ENTITY_A.BId strongly references ENTITY_A_B.BId
ENTITY_A_B.BId softly references ENTITY_B.Id
ENTITY_A_B.Name keeps value of ENTITY_B.Name
```